# How to add HQL clause (WHERE COUNT()< MAX_VAL) to complex query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, count, hql

Now my query returns map of flight and its ticket count.
My aim is to exclude full flights from query result `(count(t) < f.aircraft.model.passengersSeatsQuantity)`. But I cannot manage to create such query. Thus now I have to exclude full flights within method, and that is depressing, because i think there should be way to do it in query. Can anyone help to build query? p.s. i am now allowed to use Criteria API

```
String queryString = "SELECT f, COUNT(t)"
            + " FROM Flight f"
            + " JOIN FETCH f.tickets AS t"
            + " WHERE f.departureAirport=:departureAirport"
            + " GROUP BY t.flight"
            + " ORDER BY f.id ASC";

Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("departureAirport", departureAirport);

Map<Flight, Long>) flightsTicketCountMap =
            query.getResultList().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(resultElement -> (Flight) (((Object[]) resultElement)[0]),
                    resultElement -> (Long) (((Object[]) resultElement)[1])));

//below i exclude full flights from map, but i want to do it in query
Map<Flight, Long> availableFlightTicketPriceMap = new HashMap();
for (Map.Entry<Flight, Long> entry : flightsTicketCountMap.entrySet()) {
        flight = entry.getKey();
        ticketsQuantity = entry.getValue();
        if (flight.getAircraft().getModel().getPassengersSeatsQuantity() > ticketsQuantity) {
            availableFlightTicketPriceMap.put(flight, calculateTicketPrice(tariffsDetails, flight, ticketsQuantity));
        }
    }
```

UPDATE.
aircraft and model have eager policy, but `HAVING COUNT(t) < f.aircraft.model.passengersSeatsQuantity` hot working with exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column aircraftmo3_.passenger_seats_quantity in having clause`

```
public class Flight{
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name = "aircraft_id")
    private Aircraft aircraft;
}

public class Aircraft{
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "model_id")
  private AircraftModel model;
}

public class AircraftModel{
  @Column(name = "passenger_seats_quantity")
  @Range(min = 0, max = 450)
  private Integer passengersSeatsQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `HAVING` clause?

```
SELECT f, COUNT(t)
FROM Flight f
JOIN FETCH f.tickets AS t
WHERE f.departureAirport=:departureAirport
GROUP BY t.flight
HAVING COUNT(t) < f.aircraft.model.passengersSeatsQuantity
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```

Comment: i've just tried and got com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'aircraftmo4_.passenger_seats_quantity' in 'having clause'
But aircraft and model have eager fetching policy, so than  tied to add JOIN f.aircraft JOIN f.aircraft.model and that not helped too (same exception). hm, weird behavour

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `HAVING` is what you want here.  You may have to sort out your own HQL, and you are most likely to do that before I can as you have the schema/entities in front of you.

Comment: ok, thank you! I'll keep trying to make it work. Just updated my question with additional info